# Return dict of attribute name and value of type

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, attributes

```
NewType=type('nt',(object,),{'x':'hello'})
n=NewType()
n.x
'hello'
```

How do I obtain the dict `{'x':'hello'}` from n?

Failed attempts:  `n.__bases__, n.__dir__, n.__dict__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a *class attribute*, so `NewType.__dict__` would work.

Alternative routes would be:

```
type(n).__dict__
vars(NewType)
vars(type(n))
```

Demo:

```
>>> NewType=type('nt',(object,),{'x':'hello'})
>>> n=NewType()
>>> n.x
'hello'
>>> NewType.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'nt' objects>, 'x': 'hello', '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'nt' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> type(n).__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'nt' objects>, 'x': 'hello', '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'nt' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(NewType)
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'nt' objects>, 'x': 'hello', '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'nt' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(type(n))
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'nt' objects>, 'x': 'hello', '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'nt' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

The class dictionary has a few more attributes in it (including `__dict__` itself).

Comment: @mgilson: I'd only use `n.__class__` on old-style classes, really. Compare it with `n.__str__()` vs. `str(n)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah, that's the argument that I typically hear (read).  _But_, the `str` function isn't overloaded to do multiple things like `type`, so there is some difference.

Comment: @mgilson: `next()` instead of `iterable.__next__()`, `int(obj)` instead of `obj.__index__()`, etc. And I haven't even touched on the operator magic methods such as `.__eq__()`. :-)

Comment: @eryksun: that's only because attribute access is proxied, but `type()` doesn't look at `__class__` as `weakref.proxy()` is implemented in C.

Comment: @eryksun: as the [`weakref.proxy()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.proxy) puts it: *This supports use of the proxy in **most contexts*** (emphasis mine); `type()` is not a context they support.

Comment: @eryksun: ah, that wasn't clear from your comment. :-)

Comment: FWIW, I've started using `type(n).__dict__` more often in my own code for exactly the reason you stated, but I still feel conflicted about it.  All of the example builtins you stated are (more or less)  enhanced wrappers around the dunder methods.  (technically, `str` and `int` are _types_ so it is a little fuzzy here...).  `type` doesn't wrap a method but an attribute, doesn't work for old-style classes and has another use entirely (making completely new types).  Anyway, I'm not trying to defend one way or the other -- Just state my conflictedness.